# Passing two parameters to input type file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, image-uploading

In my scenerio, i'm using CarrierWave to upload images. But my "Image" model is polymorphic, because more than one model use "Image" model. And for each model, there are 4 different image types (Icon, Title, Regular, Slider). So i will make "ENUM" for them in "Image" model. But the problem is that, in "new" or "edit" views, how will i know, which file upload for which "Image Type"?

So here is my Image Model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    enum image_type: {icon: 1, title: 2, regular: 3, slider: 4}
end
```

Here is the Service Model (This model is one of the models which will have images):

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images, as: :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

end
```

And here is my _form.html.erb:

```
<div class="control-group">
   <!-- <label class="control-label" for="input1">Adı</label> -->
   <div class="controls">
      <%= f.input :service_name, input_html: { class: "span6", id: "input1"}, label: "Hizmet Adı" %>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
   <!-- <label class="control-label" for="inputRemarks">Adres</label> -->
   <div class="controls">
      <%= f.input :service_description, input_html: { class: "span12 wysihtml5", rows: "6"}, as: :text, label: "Hizmet Açıklaması" %>

   </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
   <----- THIS PART IS FOR FILE UPLOAD ----------->
   <div class="controls">
      <label class="control-label">Hizmet Büyük Resimi</label> 
      <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
        <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt=""/></div>
        <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
        <div>
          <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Resim Seç</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Değiştir</span>
          <%= f.input :images, input_html: { type: :file, class: "default"}, wrapper: false, label: false %></span>
          <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Sil</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <----- THIS PART IS FOR FILE UPLOAD ----------->
   </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
   <!-- <label class="control-label" for="input2">Soyadı</label> -->
   <div class="controls">
      <%= f.input :meta_keywords, input_html: { class: "span6", id: "input2"}, label: "Anahtar Kelimeler" %>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="form-actions">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
     Kaydet
  <% end %>


   <!-- <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button> -->
</div>
```

I'm new to rails, so is it difficult or not, i don't know yet. But this type of solution looks good to me. But i'm stuck in this question and i need your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, as i said i'm so new to Rails and there is a "fields_for" form helper in Rails. So for nested attributes, you can use "fields_for" form helpers to do it. In my scenerio, i added hidden fields for that.